# Make text to the default style

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor in my asp.net application, What I want to if some has change the text color to red or green etc., then automatically text color change to the default color (Black).

What should I do for that?

Comment: why like this, its my client requirement, if some one don't know the ans. then should not downvote the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get what you want:

**1.** Fiddle with the style plugin code to set the text color

**2.** The more promising way: after tinymce init you could bind a handler to the UI-Style-Elements in order to decide when to set the text color to black